# How to form the number 8 from 5,5,5, and 1?

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

How would I be able to create the number $8$ from the numbers $5,5,5,1$ using only addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. There is no factorial and no square root allowed.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say whether you allow concatenation.  I assume the desired solution is $8=5+\frac {15}5$  If you prefer decimals, you can do $\frac {1}{.5 \cdot .5 \cdot .5}$

Comment: Sir how do you do that ??????

Comment: Do what?  Find the answer or make the pretty $\frac {15}5$?  We have lots of $5$s, so it is natural to look for $3$.

Comment: You can't concatenate. !!! Really if you do that that's breaking the rules of mathematics....

Comment: In puzzles like this concatenation is often allowed.  The first one I saw, which was *long* ago, was [four fours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours).  You just need to be clear on the rules.   Sometimes decimal points are allowed, sometimes repeating fractions.  With your rules there may not be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing two more 5 s from the picture , if you really missed then we can use (((5+1)*5)+5+5)/5 =8 otherwise it's no way possible to get 8 with your question...